# How to display images based on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Images names has this structure:

```
16-04-2015
15-04-2015
14-04-2015_1
14-04-2015_2
13-04-2015
12-04-2015
11-04-2015
```

The images are placed one a folder in the project and are loaded with the image date as the name. There are two buttons next and previous buttons. When buttons are clicked the corresponding image will be displayed based on the date . How to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide code for what you've implemented, and details on what specifically isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution but without _1 and _2 since the date code don't know if there are two images with same date.

```js
var div = $('div');
var now = new Date();
function formatDate(date) {
  return  (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
}
div.html(formatDate(now));
$('#next').click(function() {
  var date = new Date(div.text());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  div.html(formatDate(date));
});
$('#prev').click(function() {
  var date = new Date(div.text());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  div.html(formatDate(date));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button id="next">next</button>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
```

Instead of div html you can use src attribute `img.attr('src')` and `img.attr('src', date)`

Comment: thanks for reply we will try as you said

Comment: we got starting current date but we have 5 images like date 14,15,16,17.In this image 17 date is latest can you Please help how to get latest image in my image folder

Comment: You can't do this from client you need to read directory on the server and then get last image.

Comment: thanks for reply .you code Fine .but can any possibility with  _1 and _2 .Please help me

Comment: @PavanAlapati same as with last image you will need help from the server (like php for example), you will need to list all images, you can save them in array and then increment or decrement the index.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible and all the trick is to parse those images name and set them as  id's and sort them.

Since you didn't give us any code example here is a general carousel that will display the "images" (`div.image` in the example) in the date order and index order.

```js
$(function(){ // On DOM ready
  
  //Define all needed:
  var $btn_prev = $('button#prev'),
      $btn_next = $('button#next'),
      $container = $('.container'),
      imageSelector = 'div.image',
      firstExposedImage = 0,
      imageDates   = [];
    
  //Prepare sorted image array:
  $container.find(imageSelector).each(function(){
     idAtt = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
     i     = 1;
     if (idAtt.length === 2) { i = parseInt(idAtt[1]); }
     newId = idAtt[0]+"_"+i;
     idAtt = idAtt[0];
     numbers = idAtt.match(/\d+/g); 
     date = new Date(numbers[2], numbers[0]-1, numbers[1]);
     imageDates.push({ id:"#"+newId, date: date, i:i});
     $(this).attr('id',newId);
  });
    
  //Sorting function:
  imageDates.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.date - b.date || a.i - b.i;
  });
    
  //Add position to container:
  $container.data('pos', firstExposedImage);
    
  //Expose First image:
  console.log(imageDates[firstExposedImage].id);
  $(imageDates[firstExposedImage].id).show();  
    
  //Button behavior:
  $btn_prev.click(function(){
      expose_image(-1);
  });
  $btn_next.click(function(){
      expose_image(1);
  });
    
  //Toggle images function:
  function expose_image(move) {
      cur = $container.data('pos');
      target = cur + move;
      if (target < 0) target = imageDates.length-1;
      if (target > imageDates.length-1) target = 0;
      $container.data('pos', target);
      $(imageSelector + ":visible" ).hide();
      $(imageDates[target].id).show();
  }
  
  
});
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:160px;
}
div.image {
  display:none;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  font-size:26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='image' id='14-04-2005'>14-04-2005</div>
  <div class='image' id='17-04-2005'>17-04-2005</div>
  <div class='image' id='14-07-2006_3'>14-07-2006_3</div>
  <div class='image' id='14-02-2001'>14-02-2001</div>
  <div class='image' id='13-04-2012'>13-04-2012</div>
  <div class='image' id='14-07-2006_2'>14-07-2006_2</div>
  <div class='image' id='14-07-2006_1'>14-07-2006_1</div>
</div>
<button id='prev'>prev</button>
<button id='next'>next</button>
```